# IShouldInitialize interface equivalent in ABP Framework

Tags: initialization, inversion-of-control, abp

I search for an equivalent of the `IShouldInitialize` interface in ABP.IO framework.

In ASP.NET Boilerplate, the interface marked the framework to run an `Initialize` method: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#ishouldinitialize-interface

But I don't find an equivalent in ABP.IO. Does it exists?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Could you check this doc, please? Hope it may answer your question. https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Dependency-Injection

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Could you please tell me which part adds an initialization mechanism for a service? I don't find it.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe, ITransientDependency is what you look for, If I understand correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure my need was understood. My need does not concern the need for lazy injection. I need an `Initialize` method in one of my class to run some operations that should be done before all other calls, but can't / should not be done in constructor of the class